# Race Conditions with pthreads in C

Tags: c, pthreads, race-condition, file-pointer

I am new to pthreads in C and I am writing a simple program that find words in several files in parallel. However, whenever I input more than one file the output varies, suggesting that there is a race condition that I am not fixing in my code. Could you please help me fix it?

The following snippet is in main, making the pthreads.

```
    int i = 0;
char *word = "Pluto"; //Word to be found

Message messages[argc-1];
pthread_t threads[argc-1];
for(i; i < argc - 1; i++){
    messages[i].file = argv[i + 1];
    messages[i].word = word;
    messages[i].fp   = fopen(argv[i + 1], "r");
    int  iret = pthread_create( &threads[i], NULL, threadFindWord, (void*) &(messages[i]));
}for(i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++){
    pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
}
```

The function that each thread calls:

```
Message *msg;
msg = (Message *) ptr;

int numFound = ffindWord(msg->fp, msg->word);

printf("File %s has %i occurences of the word %s\n", msg->file, numFound, msg->word);

fclose(msg->fp);
pthread_exit(NULL);
```

The following is the code for finding a word in a file)

```
int findWord(char * file, char * word){
 char * current = strtok(file, " ,.\n");
 int sum = 0;
 while (current != NULL){
    //printf("%s\n", current);
    if(strcmp(current, word) == 0)
        sum+=1;
    current = strtok(NULL, " ,.\n");
}
return sum;
}



int ffindWord(FILE *fp, char *word){

 fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
 long pos = ftell(fp);
 fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
 char *bytes = malloc(pos);
 fread(bytes, pos, 1, fp);
 bytes[pos-1] = '\0';

 int sum = findWord(bytes, word);

 free(bytes);
 return sum;
 }
```

For clarification, the problem is that I get different results upon consecutive runs of the program. A call
    $programname file1 file2
Prints different results than a same call called right after. Note, however, that the program works when only one file is passed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How does the output vary? Different results from the same file or intermingled output?

Comment: @hmjd Yes the output varies. For example: `$ ./a.out blu bla` outputs `File blu has 0 occurences of the word Pluto` `File bla has 5 occurences of the word Pluto` and the same command right after `$ ./a.out blu bla` outputs `File bla has 1 occurences of the word Pluto`
`File blu has 4 occurences of the word Pluto`

Comment: no need to cast to or from `void*`

Comment: @JensGustedt The cast shouldn't really affect the output

Comment: Do you get consistent results if you repeatedly run `$ ./a.out blu`? Can you post `ffindWord()` function definition? Also the compiler command you used to build.

Comment: @pretobomba, sure, that's why put it in a comment. But it distracts :)

Comment: @pretobomba Make sure that ur ffindWord() function is thread safe.

Comment: @hmjd yes I get consistent result if there is only one file as input i.e. `$ ./a.out blu` gives the right result

Comment: @hmjd the command was gcc -lpthread program.c

Comment: I dont think this is the problem, but you dont need to call pthread_exit if the thread func is exiting normally.

Comment: @pretobomba, use `-pthread` instead as there may be macros required as well as the just linking with the library.

Comment: See my answer below.  Use strtok_r not strtok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strtok keeps an internal pointer that is global...  use [strtok_r](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r).

Answer (score 1):

This results in undefined behaviour as it goes beyond the end of the `messages` and `threads` arrays:

```
Message messages[argc-1];
pthread_t threads[argc-1];
for(i; i < argc; i++){
```

and may be the cause of the problems. It may work by chance when only 1 thread is executed.

Try changing to (or something similar):

```
int i;
Message messages[argc-1];
pthread_t threads[argc-1];
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    messages[i - 1].file = argv[i];
    messages[i - 1].word = word;
    messages[i - 1].fp   = fopen(argv[i], "r");
    int iret = pthread_create(&threads[i - 1],
                               NULL,
                               threadFindWord,
                               (void*)&(messages[i - 1]));
}

for(i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++)
{
    pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. the loops should run from 0 to (argc-1) to generate the correct 0-based indexes for the arrays.

Comment: @MartinJames, in my example solution `i - 1` is used to index `messages` and `threads` in the first `for`. The OP wants to skip `argv[0]` as it is the program name.

Comment: It's easier to understand and code, if index is maintained as 0. Inside **for() do a simple if(i==0) continue**.

Comment: I changed to what you suggested, however the problem still persists

Comment: @pretobomba, so perhaps you should try to give us a better description of what the problem is. What do you expect -- what do you get.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having the output from each thread mixed together in random ways, you need to buffer the output of each thread and then display them one at time.

For your case, the easiest way to do this would be to add a `char *thread_output` field (and `thread_output_size` field) to the `Message` structure, and then do something like this in your main thread:

```
for(i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++)
{
    pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
    printf("%s", messages[i - 1].thread_output);
}
```

You'll probably also want to implement a function that makes sure the `thread_output` buffer is large enough and then uses `vsnprintf()` to add new text to the buffer, so you can use it just like you would've used `printf()`.

For example:

```
void add_thread_output(int thread_number, const char *template, ...) {
    int old_length;
    int length;
    char *temp;

    va_start(ap, template);
    length = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, template, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    old_length = messages[thread_number - 1].thread_output_size;
    temp = realloc(messages[thread_number - 1].thread_output, old_length + length + 1);
    if(temp == NULL) {
        /* Set a flag or something */
    } else {
        va_start(ap, template);
        vsnprintf(&temp[old_length], length + 1, template, ap);
        va_end(ap);
        messages[thread_number - 1].thread_output_size += length;
        messages[thread_number - 1].thread_output = temp;
    }
}
```

*Note: Any example code above is for the purpose of example only, and isn't tested or guaranteed to compile or work, and also isn't necessarily the most efficient way of doing it. E.g. allocating more space than you need (to avoid doing `realloc()` every time you add something to a thread's output buffer) may be a good idea.*